# Javascript dialog box with table inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dialog box with a table and many rows. The dialog appears when a user clicks a button. I have my dialog box created and it seems to work, but when I refresh the page I see the contents (the table) of the box on the top of my page even before I click the button. After I click the button the table will show in the dialog correctly, and get removed from the top of the page.

Is there a way to hide the top table when you refresh the page and only show it when the dialog button is clicked?

```js
function popupRackParamChecker(){
  $("#dialog-rackParams").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 550,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      draggable: false,
      buttons: {
      Confirm: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="dialog" title="Parameters">
<table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Kevin</td>
            <td>Kevin@example.com</td>
            <td>Kevin</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I just had to set `style="display:none"` in the html

```
<div id="dialog-rackParams" title="Rack Parameters" style="display:none">
```